# in influxdb2, How to design a task for count the number of different value of a field?

Tags: influxdb, flux

I have a "profile" bucket, contain a "stack_stat" measurement, that tags only has `pid` and field only has `stack`,  like below:

```
bucket: profile
------
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main"    
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main"    
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main;foo" 
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main;bar" 
stack_stat,pid="222" stack="main"     
stack_stat,pid="222" stack="main;foo" 
stack_stat,pid="222" stack="main;foo"
```

> Please note that their `_time` values are different

I created a task to count the number of occurrences of different stacks of the same process. For the above data, **I am expect the following results(stack is still a field):**

```
bucket:profile_downsample
------
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main",count=2     
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main;foo",count=1 
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main;bar",count=1 
stack_stat,pid="222" stack="main",count=1     
stack_stat,pid="222" stack="main;foo",count=2
```

When using the aggregate function count, I cannot find a way to keep the `_time` column, and the `_time` value is in the `_time` value set of the aggregated data.

i designed a task. **but that cannot meet expectations, because it will lost some data**：

```
option task = {name: "task2", every: 1d}

data = from(bucket: "profile")
    |> range(start: -task.every)
    |> filter(fn: (r) =>
        (r["_measurement"] == "stack_stat"))
    |> duplicate(as: "stack", column: "_value")
    |> group(columns: ["_measurement", "_stop", "pid", "stack"])
    |> count(column: "_value")
    |> to(
        tagColumns: ["pid"],
        fieldFn: (r) =>
            ({"count": r._value, "stack": r.stack}),
        bucket: "profile_downsample",
        timeColumn: "_stop",
```

For these three rows of data, because `_time` and `pid`(tags) are the same, only one data will be left:

```
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main",count=2     
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main;foo",count=1 
stack_stat,pid="111" stack="main;bar",count=1
```

There is another solution, the `stack` be set to tag, but I think that the efficiency is very low because the value of the `stack` field is large.

Therefore, **I am looking for a solution to solve the problems, and "stack" is still the field**, and I have been thinking about it for a long time. I will be very grateful if I get some suggestions :smile:

My English is not good, please point out if there are some mistakes, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

ok, I just found a function "reduce" that can solve the problem, although efficient could very low.

```
option task = {name: "task2", every: 1d}

from(bucket: "profile")
|> range(start: -task.every)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "stack_info")
|> pivot(columnKey: ["_field"], rowKey: ["_time"], valueColumn: "_value")
|> duplicate(as: "count", column: "stack")
|> group(columns: ["stack","_measurement"])
|> reduce(fn: (r, accumulator) => ({ count: 1 + accumulator.count , _time : r._time}), 
identity: {count:0,_time : now()})
|> to(bucket: "profile_downsample",
tagColumns: ["id"], fieldFn: (r) => ({"count": r["count"], "stack": r["stack"]} ))
```